# Routing error using node/express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to create my first MEAN stack application using a course on PluralSight. I've set up my routing like so:

```
app.get('*', function (reg, res) {
    res.render('index');
});
```

I've created a scripts.jade file that holds all the scripts:

```
script(type="text/javascript", src="/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="/vendor/angular/angular.min.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="/vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="/vendor/angular-route/angular-route.min.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="/app/app.js")
```

Which I then include in my layout.jade

The error I'm encountering is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < app.js:1

When I click to check app.js it shows the html of the index file

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><base href="/">
```

So I'm thinking my file reference for app.js in the scripts.js is wrong. But I can't see how I can fix it. All the files in /vendor/ do get resolved, it's just the app.js that's going wrong.

Here's a look on the file structure:

- Root solution

  - app

    - app.js
    - app.ts
  - public

    - vendor

      - angular

        - angular.min.js
  - server

    - includes

      - layout.jade
      - scripts.jade

When I move the files app.js and app.js.map to the public folder and then request like this:

```
script(type="text/javascript", src="/app.js")
```

The error is resolved.

Comment: So you probably use `app.use(express.static....);` to serve your static files from public directory and since app.js is not in public directory express.static handler can't see it then `app.get('*'....);` catches the request and renders index page. That's expected behaviour. I can see you also have app.ts file so if you are generating app.js from app.ts using some build tool then make sure the app.js is saved to public directory.

Comment: `since app.js is not in public directory` yup, this was it. The public folder is the root, as set in server.ts. Moved the folder and everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

To use the view engine in the express you have to include the view engine in the modules.

app.set('view engine', 'jade');